# Python - sys("clr") behaving strangely in relation to calls in code

Tags: python-3.x

I'm currently doing a homework assignment for an intro to programming class (Last time I coded was pre Covid and I need the refresher).

The program I'm using requires me to fetch data from an API. Currently, I'm trying to set up a loop that forces the user to enter a correct zip code. I want the screen to clear after the user enters the zip code and then display whether or not the API found that zip code.  The problem is that my sys("cls) commands don't work as intended (see comments) and the error case causes (what appears to be an infinite loop that clears the screen perpetually and doesn't display the input command for the user.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

> Note: Variables are all declared above the while loop and work properly

```py
#Imports for clarity
from os import system as sys
from time import sleep as pause
import requests

#   Get zip code from user and refresh screen
    while (status == False):
        zCode = str(input("Please enter a valid United States zip code: "))
        sys("cls") # THIS cls doesn't seem to activate
        
#       Get lat and lon data from API and convert it to a usable JSON format
        gll = f"http://api.openweathermap.org/geo/1.0/zip?zip={zCode},{cCode}&appid={apiKey}"
        llResults = requests.get(gll, headers=headers)
        
        if (llResults.status_code == 200):
            print("Status: Request OK")
            pause(3)
            sys("cls") # THIS cls activates the second the print statement finishes
            status = True
        else:
            print("Status: Request Error")
            pause(3)
            sys("cls") # THIS cls activates as soon as the print statement is shown
            status = False
```

**Input: Correct zip code**

- Expected screen to clear, followed by "Status: Request OK" and a 3 second pause
  Result:
- Screen doesn't clear until less than 1 second after "Status Request OK" THEN pauses for 3 seconds before shutdown

**Input: Incorrect zip code**

- Expected screen to clear, followed by "Status: Request Error" and a 3 second pause
  Result:
- Screen doesn't clear until less than 1 second after "Status Request OK" THEN pauses for 3 seconds before looping back.
- Input statement displays for a fraction of a second and is cleared
- Program does not shut down
- Enter valid zip code on blank screen and get persistent negative feedback loop